# Xcode property list editor shows Mac app attributes instead of iPhone app attributes. How do I fix it?

Tags: iphone, xcode, macos, property-list

My Xcode is configured for iPhone dev, and it worked well until yesterday.
But it's property list editor currently shows me Mac app's attributes for my iPhone project which includes 'Java', "plugin" and "quicklook" related items.

OK, I can input them manually, but it means something wrong to my IDE, so it does not sure it works correctly anymore. so I want to fix this up. And I want to know why this happen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it.
Xcode shows Mac app attributes for 'Window based iPhone project' with 'Core Data'. Find in other type of projects. I'll report this to Apple as a bug.